# Сглаживание изображения

Tags: android, java, изображения

При изменении размера векторной картинки, её края становятся лесенкообразными, можно ли как то с этим бороться?

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях бывает нужно где-то как-то включить сглаживание изображения.


Comment: >При изменении размера векторной картинки, её края становятся лесенкообразными

Сударь, вы что-то путаете. Векторная картинка не может так масштабироваться - может все таки растровая?

Comment: чем пользуетесь для отображения картинки? в каком формате картинка? Или вы думаете, что это очевидно?

Comment: ясно, понятно.

Comment: Нет именно векторная, обычные иконки в png вот с этого сайта http://www.flaticon.com/. Я использую imageView в качестве контейнера. Используя высоту экрана я делаю квадратный контейнер и растягиваю в нем изображение с помощью scaleType="fitXY". Изображения изначально тоже квадратные.

Comment: @nekaneka PNG это растровый формат - не векторный...

Comment: Понятно, ушел читать про SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть 2 способа решения этой проблемы:

1. Взять несколько разных иконок (обычно провайдеры иконок дают несколько разных разрешений) и раскидать картинки по разным res/drawable-xxx в зависимости от разрешения - [инструкции здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) - тогда в зависимости от разрешения экрана ось будет "подкладывать" нужные картинки
2. Если нет такой возможности то надо применить метод `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` - в зависимости от флага `filtered` - будет меняться качество масштабирования.